# I tried to run QGIS using python but I couldn't get any output on screen?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

```
uri ="C:/Users/rajagopalv/Desktop/poi_sunnyvale.csvdelimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("|", "x", "y")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "address_sunny", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This my code as per the http://docs.qgis.org/ but I couldn't get the output layer on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

If you looked here, there is "?" between name of file and "delimiter". 
Hope it helps.

Comment: uri = "C:/Users/rajagopalv/Desktop/poi_sunnyvale.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("|", "longitude", "latitude")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "address_sunny", "|")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)                                  this code is working but giving an error                                             Failed to load:Unknown error

Comment: Try if it is possible to open that file. E.g.
        try:
            my_file = open("C:/Users/rajagopalv/Desktop/poi_sunnyvale.csv","r")
       except:
           print "Failed to open file"
If it won't write "Failed to open file" then your csv is probably broken.